# What is the most "Icarus" Icarus set axiom?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

We call a set $X ⊆ V_{λ+1}$ an **Icarus set** if there is an elementary embedding $j : L(X, V_{λ+1}) ≺ L(X, V_{λ+1})$ with $\mathrm{crit}(j)< λ$.

But this raises the question: **What is the most "Icarus" Icarus set like?**

> If $V_{λ+1}$ is Icarus, is strongly implied by $(V_{λ+1})^{♯}$, that
> is strongly implied by $(V_{λ+1})^{♯♯}$. [Dimonte, 2017]
>
> If $\Theta^{M}<\Theta^{L(X, V_{λ+1})}$ then we consider “X is an
> Icarus set” as something stronger than “M is an Icarus set”. [Dimonte, 2011]

Even with "$M=(V_{λ+1})^{<\gamma♯}$" or "$M=E^0_{\infty}(V_{λ+1})$" or "$M=E^{j_{<\omega}}_{\infty}(V_{λ+1})$", according to the previous deduction, they cannot be the most "Icarus" Icarus set.

I looked up the literature [Woodin, 2011]. AD-Conjecture is indeed very good, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Of course I can't make sure I'm not missing anything, it's too long.

---

2022-04-18:

Well, I now probably understand that AD-Conjecture can hold an Icarus set with the maximum consistency strength. But this does not convince me that:

1. Perhaps there could also be a forcing-axiom-style (Martin's maximum? Ω-logic?)/powerset-maximal-style (V-logic?) Icarus set with maximum consistency strength based on their set-theoretic philosophy.
2. There is no known relative consistency analysis/ordinal analysis conclusion that the candidates are indeed the ones with the maximum consistency strength.
3. **Does it really require a very large consistency strength just to wish to hold all sets $X ⊆ V_{λ+1}$ that can be used for embedding?** What is the difference between this and Kunen inconsistency that prevents us from proving it in ZFC?

---

**References**

[Dimonte, 2011] Dimonte, V. (2011). Very Large Cardinals and Elementary Embeddings Properties

[Dimonte, 2017] Dimonte, V. (2017). I0 and rank-into-rank axioms.

[Woodin, 2011] Woodin, W. H. (2011). Suitable extender models II: beyond ω-huge.

Comment: How would the following quote from Dimonte's "$I0$ and rank-into-rank axioms" (pg. 61) help you answer your question (if at all):  "Trivially, if $I0(\lambda)$ holds, (and in fact every set in $L(V_{\lambda + 1})$ $\cap$ $V_{\lambda + 2}$ ) is Icarus.  On the other hand, a well-ordering of $V_{\lambda + 1} $cannot be Icarus, because of Kunen's theorem."

Comment: *$V_{\lambda + 1}$ (and in fact...

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin 1. $E^0_0=L(V_{\lambda + 1})\cup V_{\lambda + 2}$, So $E^0_1$ is more "Icarus" than it. 2. $I0(\lambda)$ is itself a dangerous and alleged violation of the axioms of Kunen inconsistency and HOD conjecture. Because $Con(ZF + \lambda\text{-}DC + I0(\lambda))\to Con(ZF + \lambda\text{-}DC + I0(\lambda) + j\uparrow 
 V_{\lambda+2})$. [*]Schlutzenberg, F. (2020). On the consistency of ZF with an elementary embedding from $ V_ {\lambda+ 2} $ into $ V_ {\lambda+ 2} $. https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.01077

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I'll take a look.

Comment: In '1', shouldn't the $\cup$ be a $\cap$ in the definition of $E^{0}_{0}$?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin I wrote it wrong, the system won't allow me to change it, my bad. This definition is from Definition 32 of [Woodin, 2011], which I can ensure.

Comment: Would't it be nice if the system would....

Comment: Do you conjecture that there is a maximal $E^{0}_{\alpha}$ and is that consistent with $I0(\lambda)$?